# Why would my apple watch UDID get associated with my iOS Developer Account twice?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

Hello there everyone,

I just got my apple watch and I set it up for development using XCode. However, it is currently taking two slots out of my 100 device quota.

Both devices show with the same name and the same UDID one below the other.

I have not been able to explain this to my manager.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to Apple's support.

Comment: I asked this question in the Apple forum, but I did not find a way to contact Dev support without exhausting a support session for something kind of trivial like this. I thought someone in the stackoverflow community has run into the same issue and could provide me with some time of answer. Maybe you can point me in the right direction? @ceejayoz

Comment: This happened to me as well.  SO usually has better answers as well :-)
BTW, no resolution.  I don't want to disable and invalidate the provisioning profiles.  Not sure if the current state of things is causing trouble deploying to the watch or if it's just Xcode flakiness.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. Wondering if it's related to not being able to install the app on the watch...